# How to have items in a flex container allow their nested children to appear below it onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, nested

I have a flex container with flex direction row and a series of items in it that renders to the screen like the below image:

[image: Image 1]

After clicking on one of these items, I need a series of items to appear below it. For example, after clicking on 'Top Level Item 1' the below items should appear like in this image below:

[image: Image 2]

While I know it's possible to place two containers (one that contains all the top levels items and another that contains all the bottom level items) on top of each other and simply update the bottom one onClick, this causes alignment issues when more items are added or non-items are added to the top level.

Instead, I'm trying to find a way to have the bottom level items nested within its associated top level item. This approach works, but obviously it will push the border down like in the image below:

[image: Image 3]
How can I achieve the layout of Image 2 onClick, but still have the individual bottom level item divs nested within its associated top level item div?

For example, in a way similar to:

```
               <div>
                    <div>Top Level Item 1</div>
                    <div>
                        <div>bottom Level Item 1</div>
                        <div>bottom Level Item 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Position: absolute on the dropdown items will not work if there is a height in place on the bordered nav and the items are centered within in. So I am trying to find a way to account for that use case as well. For example, this is what occurs if you place a height on the container and position: absolute on the dropdown items.

[image]

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: You should use position: absolute. Maybe look for existing Dropdown css/js.

Comment: position: absolute might be a good starting point. it does seem to currently achieve the right effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `position:absolute` is indeed the solution (I started working on it and saw a comment that was a bit quicker).

I still wanted to do the challenge, let me know if this is the result you desire.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.level').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    const toggleNode = [...el.childNodes].filter(child => child.classList && child.classList.contains('secondary'));
    
    if (toggleNode.length) {
        toggleNode[0].classList[toggleNode[0].classList.contains('hidden') ? 'remove' : 'add']('hidden');
    } 
  })
})
```

```css
.flex {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 130px;
}

.level {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.secondary {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="level">
    <div>Top Level Item 1</div>
    <div class="secondary hidden">
      <div>bottom Level Item 1</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
      <div>Top Level Item 2</div>
      <div class="secondary hidden">
        <div>bottom Level Item 1</div>
        <div>bottom Level Item 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
      <div>Top Level Item 3</div>
      <div class="secondary hidden">
        <div>bottom Level Item 1</div>
        <div>bottom Level Item 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with position absolute is that if you place a height on the container that has a border and then align the items center within it, the dropdown items will no longer appear below the bordered container. sorry I should have added that part to the description.

Comment: is it a known height? Or dynamic height? Because you can put `top` property in css if you know the height. So if you have `height: 100px` you would put `top: 100px;` in the absolute positioned div. ( I changed the answer as well with this example)

Comment: I think that will absolutely position it in relation to the viewport and not the container though.

Comment: it's relative to the first relative/absolute parent.. so if you make the container with the border relative it will work (check my updated example)

Comment: `position: fixed` is relative to the viewport (check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position )

Comment: yeah, you're right. this seems to work. hopefully i don't run into edge cases :). thanks for checking it out!

Comment: @Dog if you don't want to use `position: absolute` and would rather the dropdown list push content below it down the page (prevent overlapping) then take a look at my answer that I posted

Answer (score 2):

### Grid Accordion (*NO* position: absolute)

The dropdowns are done *without* `position: absolute` so that when expanding, content below them is pushed down in the page.

To get the solid border for around the toggles, add a top and bottom border around each toggle, then using pseudo selectors add border-left to `:first-of-type` and add border-right to `:last-of-type`

You can set how many lines you want the Top Level Item to use by adding the following to any parent `.items` element: `style: --topLevelLines: [line number];`

Text in the toggles that exceeds the line limit will be truncated. Text under the line limit will be vertically centered. Not setting a value will default to a single line.

The JavaScript will check if there is a dropdown preset to add a click event listener. If there is no dropdown the `.item` will get a class of `.nodrop` and some styling is applied accordingly

```js
const lists = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('items'));

lists.forEach( list => {
  const items = Array.from(list.children);
  
  items.forEach( item => {
    const toggle = item.getElementsByClassName('toggle')[0];
    const dropdown = item.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0];
    
    dropdown ? toggle.addEventListener('click', function () { item.classList.toggle('active') }) : toggle.classList.add('nodrop');
  });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { font: 16px sans-serif; margin: 0 }


.items {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto auto -1px;
  max-width: 960px;
}
.items:last-of-type { margin: auto }
.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  
  transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle {
  border-top: 1px solid currentColor;
  border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  height: calc( var(--topLevelLines, 1) * 1.25rem + ( .5rem * 2 ) );
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  place-items: center center;
  transition: padding .25s ease-in-out;
}
.toggle.nodrop { cursor: not-allowed }
.toggle:not(.nodrop)::after {
  content: "⬇️";
  font: 1em 'Segoe UI Emoji';
  grid-area: 1/1/-1/-1;
  margin-left: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
}
.toggle:not(.nodrop):hover { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125) }
.toggle:not(.nodrop):hover::after { opacity: 1 }

.toggle > span {
  grid-area: 1/1/-1/-1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: var(--topLevelLines, 1);
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.toggle.nodrop > span { opacity: 0.5 }

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown > div {
  cursor: crosshair;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out, padding .25s ease-in-out, transform .25s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown > div:hover { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125) }

.active { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .5px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.25 ) }
.active .toggle { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) }
.active .toggle::after { transform: scaleY(-1) }
.active .dropdown {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  padding: .25rem 0
}
.active:hover { background-color: rgba(125,255,125,0.25) }

.active .dropdown > div {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  max-height: none;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.active .dropdown > div:last-of-type { margin-bottom: 0 }

.item:first-of-type .toggle { border-left: 1px solid currentColor }
.item:last-of-type .toggle { border-right: 1px solid currentColor }
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="toggle"><span>Toggle 1</span></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>bottom Level Item 1</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="toggle"><span>Toggle 2 (no children)</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="toggle"><span>Toggle 3</span></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>bottom Level Item 6</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 7</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 8</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="items" style="--topLevelLines: 2">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="toggle"><span>Toggle 4 with lots of text in it that will eventually cause it to overflow the line restrictions rhoncus arcu cum ac vestibulum volutpat a luctus parturient nascetur condimentum dui penatibus habitant vestibulum vestibulum euismod id parturient porta ullamcorper viverra ultricies per integer a. A non sit adipiscing dis orci eget ac mi mauris nunc vestibulum gravida nascetur a nisl proin sociis adipiscing netus sit. Per id est posuere a a varius habitasse imperdiet laoreet consectetur vestibulum vestibulum nec a sit euismod. Consectetur vel vitae interdum mollis dis integer etiam non adipiscing vestibulum tempor ligula ultricies laoreet semper libero ligula consequat mollis a scelerisque elit ac sed viverra. Orci per suspendisse a eleifend mus a primis a orci nam augue condimentum leo ullamcorper sem volutpat sit condimentum vestibulum a velit eros nibh non mi. Sodales lorem malesuada bibendum sem parturient ligula dis a vulputate orci suspendisse curabitur varius porttitor vestibulum adipiscing parturient nam nam cursus sagittis.</span></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>bottom Level Item 10</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 11</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="toggle"><span>Toggle 5</span></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>bottom Level Item 12</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 13</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 14</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="toggle"><span>Toggle 6</span></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>bottom Level Item 15</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 16</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 17</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 18</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="toggle"><span>Toggle 7<br>(no children)</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="items" style="--topLevelLines: 3">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="toggle"><span>Toggle 8 with lots of text in it that will eventually cause it to overflow the line restrictions rhoncus arcu cum ac vestibulum volutpat a luctus parturient nascetur condimentum dui penatibus habitant vestibulum vestibulum euismod id parturient porta ullamcorper viverra ultricies per integer a. A non sit adipiscing dis orci eget ac mi mauris nunc vestibulum gravida nascetur a nisl proin sociis adipiscing netus sit. Per id est posuere a a varius habitasse imperdiet laoreet consectetur vestibulum vestibulum nec a sit euismod. Consectetur vel vitae interdum mollis dis integer etiam non adipiscing vestibulum tempor ligula ultricies laoreet semper libero ligula consequat mollis a scelerisque elit ac sed viverra. Orci per suspendisse a eleifend mus a primis a orci nam augue condimentum leo ullamcorper sem volutpat sit condimentum vestibulum a velit eros nibh non mi. Sodales lorem malesuada bibendum sem parturient ligula dis a vulputate orci suspendisse curabitur varius porttitor vestibulum adipiscing parturient nam nam cursus sagittis.</span></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>bottom Level Item 21</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 22</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 23</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="toggle"><span>Toggle 9</span></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div>bottom Level Item 24</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 25</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 26</div>
      <div>bottom Level Item 27</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really nice extensive answer with awesome demo! Thanks for the hard work... posted it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/RwMKoKe)

Comment: @RenevanderLende Haha thank you! I surprised myself with this one to be honest. It could definitely use some work for mobile, maybe collapsing into a big accordion list instead of the grid. I’m honoured you took the time to make a codepen though, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question while working with `<details><summary>` ([MDN: Details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)) and wanted to show you an alternative solution to the accepted answer.

This example uses a `position: fixed` `<nav>` element as main parent container for three main navbar menus made up of nested `<details><summary>` elements. As these elements already incorporate an *open/close* mechanism, a Javascript `click.eventListener` is *optional* and only required when the current navbar menu should close when another navbar menu gets selected by the user ('loses  focus').

`Fixed/Absolute` postioning is only used to attach the navbar at the top of the viewport (*optional*, `relative` will work too) and draw its border.

Besides some *eye-candy* the navbar menus use regular/default CSS values.

The **snippet** (uses *optional* JS to toggle active menu):

```js
var currentDetail;

// top summary of menu only
document.querySelectorAll('.navmenu>summary').forEach(el => {
    // triggers before <details> 'toggle' event
    el.addEventListener("click", event => {
        // Parent of top summary
        const closest = event.currentTarget.closest('.navmenu');

        if (closest.open) {
            currentDetail = null; // all menus closed
        }
        else { // not null and different menu
            if ((currentDetail) && (currentDetail != closest)) {

                currentDetail.removeAttribute('open'); // close current open menu
             };
             currentDetail = closest; // save new (to be 'toggled') opened menu
        }
    });
});
```

```css
*, ::before, ::after { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box }

html, body  { width: 100%; max-width: 100% }
body        { min-height: 100vh; margin: 0 }

:root {
    --doc-lh : 1.5;     /* document line-height */
    --nav-pad: .25rem;  /* navbar padding       */
    --nav-bd : 1px;     /* navbar border size   */

    --mnu-pad: 0.25rem; /* main menu padding */
    --mnu-br : 1em;     /* border radius     */
}

nav {
    top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 999;
    position: fixed; /* or 'relative' */
 
    width: 100%;  /* fill parent width */
    height: auto; /* just making sure */

    display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: var(--nav-pad);
 }
nav::after {
    position: absolute; inset: 0; content: ""; z-index: -1;

    /* parent padding + navmenu padding + border + line-height */
    height: calc(2 * var(--nav-pad) +
                 2 * var(--mnu-pad) +
                 2 * var(--nav-bd)  +
                 var(--doc-lh) * 1em);/**/

    border: var(--nav-bd) solid black;
}

nav details { align-self: flex-start }

.navmenu {
    padding: var(--mnu-pad) calc(3 * var(--mnu-pad));
}
.navmenu[open]>summary { /* to move it below the navbar */
    padding-bottom: calc( var(--nav-pad) + 2 * var(--mnu-pad) + var(--nav-bd) )
}

/******************/
/* Eye-candy only */
/******************/
details { width: min(14rem, 100%) }
summary { cursor: pointer }

details>details,
summary + * { padding-left: 1em }           /* saw-tooth layout */

.navmenu {
    background-color: hsl(0,0%,86.3%, .95); /* Gainsboro */
    border: 1px solid hsl(0,0%,76.3%, 1);   /* Gainsboro L-10 */
    border-radius: var(--mnu-br);
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <details class="navmenu" id="det-01">
          <summary>menu 1</summary>
          <details>
              <summary>option 1.1</summary>
              <details>
                  <summary>option 1.1.1</summary>
                  <div>option text 1.1.1</div>
              </details>
              <details>
                  <summary>option 1.1.2</summary>
                  <div>option text 1.1.2</div>
              </details>
          </details>
          <details>
              <summary>option 1.2</summary>
              <div>option text 1.2</div>
          </details>
          <details>
              <summary>option 1.3</summary>
              <div>option text 1.3</div>
          </details>
      </details>

      <details class="navmenu" id="det-02">
          <summary>menu 2</summary>
          <details>
              <summary>option 2.1</summary>
              <details>
                  <summary>option 2.1.1</summary>
                  <div>option text 2.1.1</div>
              </details>
              <details>
                  <summary>option 2.1.2</summary>
                  <div>option text 2.1.2</div>
              </details>
          </details>
          <details>
              <summary>option 2.2</summary>
              <div>option text 2.2</div>
          </details>
          <details>
              <summary>option 2.3</summary>
              <div>option text 2.3</div>
          </details>
      </details>

      <details class="navmenu" id="det-03">
          <summary>menu 3</summary>
          <details>
              <summary>option 3.1</summary>
              <details>
                  <summary>option 3.1.1</summary>
                  <div>option text 3.1.1</div>
              </details>
              <details>
                  <summary>option 3.1.2</summary>
                  <div>option text 3.1.2</div>
              </details>
          </details>
          <details>
              <summary>option 3.2</summary>
              <div>option text 3.2</div>
          </details>
          <details>
              <summary>option 3.3</summary>
              <div>option text 3.3</div>
          </details>
      </details>
  </nav>
```